# Jquery gallery empty/append

Tags: jquery, append, gallery

Creating a picture gallery with a preview.  When I click on one picture it empty's the div, but it does not append the new picture. Am I missing something?

```
 <div class="thumbnails">
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=classone.jpg" id="img1" class='pic' src="classone.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=danceshoes.jpg" id="img2" class='pic' src="danceshoes.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=lakemonroe.jpg" id="img3" class='pic' src="lakemonroe.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=danceshoes.jpg" id="img4" class='pic' src="danceshoes.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=danceshoes.jpg" id="img5" class='pic' src="danceshoes.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=dance.jpg" id="img6" class='pic' src="dance.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
  </div><br/>

  <div class="preview" align="center">
    <img id="preview" src="classone.jpg" alt="N Image Loaded"/>
  </div><br/>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.pic').click(function(){
            $(".preview").remove();

        $(".preview").append(this); 
    });


});
```

Comment: You can't append to something that you've removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the new src instead of removing the preview image element:

```
 $('.pic').click(function(){
    $("#preview").attr("src",$(this).attr("src")); 
 });
```